# Video recorder that can be used with Wowza

Tags: wowza, recorder

Do you guys have any suggestions on free/paid solutions for recording video from webcam and storing it on the wowza media server? I tried the wowza recording example but I couldn't figure out how I can set the server connection as a variable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try HDFVR, a paid flash application, but very good.

Answer (score 0):

The wowza recording example should work for this.  When you say you couldn't "figure out how to set the server connection as a variable", is that from the client to tell Wowza to record, or to play back the already recorded stream? Using the built-in http provider here http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?123 will allow you to make post requests to the Wowza server to start and stop recording.

Comment: The recorder example worked out of the box but I had to provide the rtmp address in the form. I was wondering if there was some configuration file where I could set that.

Comment: That form uses the http provider, the source of which comes in the zip file Wowza provides here - http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?123. The file name is HTTPLiveStreamRecord.java.  You could modify that in the Wowa IDE(http://www.wowza.com/media-server/developers#wowza-ide) to create your own provider in which clients don't need to provide the server name.